# How can I make installed addins in RStudio visible?

Tags: r, rstudio

I installed some addins in RStudio, for instance:

```
install.packages("esquisse")

library(esquisse)
```

But when I click at the bar for addins there are none.

I can see that packages also esquisse are in the following path:

C:\Users\myusernamehere\Documents\R\win-library\4.1

Does anyone know what I can do to get and use the addins?

Comment: Did you find 'ggplot2 builder' ?

Comment: No, "ggplot2 builder" is not there.. but "ggplot2" is there

Comment: Restart rStudio.

Comment: I did.. I also restared my laptop but it doesn't helped

Comment: What version of RStudio are you using?

Comment: SOLVED: start Rstudio as admin, open tools, click on install packages, change the path to the general instead of the personal (because my personal path contains a special character Ø). Then type in the needed packages/addins I want to install.